# How to use link in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, spotify, styled-components

I'm developing spotify clone, and among them, I am developing side nav. I would like to connect the pages divided using react in sidenav using link.

this is sidebar code

```
        <SideBackground>
            <LogoImg src="https://music-b26f.kxcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/635963274692858859903160895_spotify-logo-horizontal-black.jpg"></LogoImg>

            <BrowserRouter>
                <Link to="/">
                    <Option Icon={HomeIcon} title="Home" />
                </Link>
                <Link to="/Search">
                    <Option Icon={SearchIcon} title="Search"/>
                </Link>
                <Link to="/Library">
                    <Option Icon={LibraryMusicIcon} title="Library"/>
                </Link>
            </BrowserRouter>

            <StringTitle>PLAYLIST</StringTitle>
            <Line/>
                {
                    playList.map(({ name }) => <PrintList>{name}</PrintList>)
                }
            <Option/>
        </SideBackground>
```

this is Pages view code

```
<div>
     HOME
</div>

<div>
     LIBRARY
</div>

<div>
     Search
</div>
```

Comment: You need to set Route inside the BrowserRouter, to render the appropriate component according to the path.

Answer (score 0):

If Option is component,

```html
<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
          <Option Icon={HomeIcon} title="Home" />
      </Route>
  ...
    </Switch>
<Router>
```

If doesn't work.. then check import and dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using option without select?

First you need to make router for your pages in app.js, route.js or any of your file.

```
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/search" exact component={Search} />
    <Route path="/library" exact component={Library} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

and then you can use link in your sidebar file.

```
  <SideBackground>
    <LogoImg src="https://music-b26f.kxcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/635963274692858859903160895_spotify-logo-horizontal-black.jpg"></LogoImg>

    <Link to="/">
      <span Icon={HomeIcon} title="Home">Home</span>
    </Link>
    <Link to="/Search">
      <span Icon={SearchIcon} title="Search">Search</span>
    </Link>
    <Link to="/Library">
      <span Icon={LibraryMusicIcon} title="Library">Library</span>
    </Link>

    <StringTitle>PLAYLIST</StringTitle>
    <Line />
    {playList.map(({ name }) => (
      <PrintList>{name}</PrintList>
    ))}
    <span />
  </SideBackground>
```

no need BrowserRouter here in sidebar file. for add icon you can use span or i tag option will not work with link.